# Code cannot find correct min or max using sorted lists and user input?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm new to python and I'm trying to prompt a user for 5 integers and then I am to find the minimum, maximum, and average (with other stuff later).  So I prompt and try to do a check to make sure the input is an integer.  Then I try to build a list and sort it to find the minimum and max.  The issue is when I have multiple digits in a number, the correct mini and max and average are not always found.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
# Define strings minStr = 'Minimum Value is: ' maxStr = 'Maximum Value is: ' aveStr = 'Average Value is: '


# Prompt User for Integers:

strMontyPython = 'My hovercraft is full of eels.  Let\'s sample them.' strMP2 = ' Take 5 samples and enter how many eels you saw on my hovercraft each time below.' print(strMontyPython + strMP2)

# First integer input int1 =input("Please Enter an Eel Count (as an integer).")
# Show knowledge of exceptions initially to check if integer was entered: try:
    val = int(int1) except ValueError:
    print("That's not an integer! \n Fish slap! \n Your min, max, and average will not be computed.")
         print('You\'ve Entered: ' + int1)
#  (Repeat 4 more times)  
# Define functions and useage   
# Make a list to compute min, max values: intList = [int1, int2, int3, int4, int5] 
# Sort list intList.sort()
# Find min print(minStr + intList[0]) 
# Find max print(maxStr + intList[len(intList)-1])  
# Find average value:

def averageEels(int1,int2,int3,int4,int5):
    aveEels = (int1+int2+int3+int4+int5) / (5)

    return aveEels
     print(aveStr + str(averageEels(int(int1),int(int2),int(int3),int(int4),int(int5))))
```

Comment: You don't have any code for min/ max. Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully - you're declaring

```
intList = [int1, int2, int3, ...]
```

When you read the integers, they're naturally read as strings. You can typecast them to ints, as you did with

```
val = int(int1)
```

but `int1` still remains a string, and `val` as an int. Since strings are sorted lexicographically, `10` will appear before `2`, and so on. The solution is to make sure that `int1` is typecasted to an integer before it's added to the list.

Here's a quick cleanup of your code, using a for loop instead of just repeating the code over and over:

```
intList = []
for _ in range(0, 5):
    try: 
        val = input("Please Enter an Eel Count (as an integer).")
        intList.append( int(val) )
    except ValueError:
         print("That's not an integer! ...")
```

Additionally, python actually has built-in methods for computing the min, max, and average (via "sum / size") of iterable objects like lists:

```
minimum = min(intList)
maximum = max(intList)
average = sum(intList) / len(intList)
```

You can still find those values by sorting the list if you want to, but there's no need.

And another heads-up: if you want to access the last element of a list, you can just do

```
intList[-1]
```

Negative list indices in python count from the back of the list: `-1` is the last element, `-2` is the second to last, and so on. No need to do `len(intList) - 1`.